# Explanation of llamarse and reflexive conjugation

Tags: verbos, conjunciones

Why does

> Me llamo Joe

translate to

> *I call myself Joe*

but

> Joe me llamo

Translates to

> *Joe calls me*.

I would’ve expected Joe calls me to be

> Joe me llama

Not using llamo

Comment: Me llamo Joe **does not translate to** I call myself Joe. It's: My name is Joe. in most contexts. Joe me llamó, Joe called me. Joe calls me, is Joe me llama, yes.

Answer (score 4):

I would’ve expected Joe calls me to be

> ”Joe me llama”

Exactly. "llamo" is the first person form of the verb. I'm a learner just like you, so I can't tell whether “Joe me llamo” is a grammatically wrong version of "me llamo Joe" or just a *very* rare word order used for a very specific form of emphasis, but it does not mean ”Joe calls me”.

"llamó" (note the accent; in speaking, you'd notice the difference because of the stress on the last syllable) is a third person form, but the *preterite*, and would make perfect sense, but it means "Joe called me".

Comment: I figured it out.  In past tense, “joe called me” would be Joe me llamó.  That is the third person preterite tense.

Comment: @dscore yeah, I just realized that as well.